# Ubuntu 12.04Lts

Tags: encryption

is the any method to make full disk encryption before install in Ubuntu 12.04? I see in Ubuntu 14.04 lts we can before installation , but in 12.04 I cant find it! any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using 12.04 on most of my PCs, and most of them were installed with Encryption turned on.  On my installations, encryption having been turned on means that the actual personal data folders are encrypted for ALL accounts installed on that computer, regardless of whether accounts are added or deleted.

As I recall, the choice to select this sort of data-folder encryption is presented during the installation process, not before, and neither is it negotiable after.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply, I meant full disk encryption, the password asked  even before booting ubuntu , I am using it in virtual machine , 14.04 is slow with my hardware , thats why I ues 12.04 but I need to make a full password required for booting like 14.04 , not just Home password ..

Comment: I've heard rumor of this 14.04 slowness.  I have recurrently heard this complaint about each new version, and for a while I too was complaining.  Without fail I've witnessed as each new installation ironed out its bugs without assistance and became fast again.

Comment: @taha33 A BIOS boot password would satisfy your requirements, and would leave Ubuntu a lot easier to troubleshoot if/when anything ever goes wrong. Besides, all the Ubuntu program files are freely available to anyone, why bother encrypting them? If your data (in home and elsewhere) is encrypted, isn't that what's worth protecting?